# SSH into a machine using PHP

Tags: php, ssh, shell-exec

I'm trying to

- SSH into my VM
- Go to a specific directory
- Run a Script

---

My command

```
ssh user@45.12.129 "cd ~/scripts; pwd; ./startVM.sh"
```

---

**PHP**

```
$cmd = 'ssh user@45.12.129 "cd ~/scripts; pwd; ./startVM.sh";
$data = shell_exec($cmd);
```

I'm not sure when to input my password. 
I hope someone can fill out what I missed.

Comment: Not a good idea to enable one to log into a machine remotely as root. Also try not to run things as root. Sort out file permissions to run it as another account. Enhances safety

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The easiest (though not necessarily most secure) way would be to create an passwordless ssh key and add that to your VM:

- run `ssh-keygen` to create a new public/private keypair if you haven't already (or if you want to create a new key just for this purpose)
- Put the generated public key in ~/.ssh/authorized_keys for the user in the VM. Make sure this file is only readable and writable by the target user. (It should have mode 0500.)
- ssh will now work without a password. (In effect, the private key *is* the password.)
- If you want to specify a specific key to use, specify with `ssh -i path-to-key-file`.

**Warning:** Keep in mind that allowing remote code execution can be very dangerous, especially when the target is the root account. If this were a local VM, you should be relatively safe, but do be cautious when using this technique in general, especially over the internet. You can very easily shoot yourself in the foot like this.

You probably want to create a non-root user in your VM for this purpose. If that user requires root privileges to complete its task, then grant access only to the *specific* functionality it needs with `sudo` and an appropriate `sudoers` file entry.

Comment: Addition: to make this more secure, you could restrict the authorized SSH key to one given certain command by prepending `command="..."` in the authorized keys file.

Answer (score 2):

Can you try something like this?

```
        if(!($con = ssh2_connect($ip, $port))){
            echo'cannot connect';
        } else {
            //Auth
            if(!ssh2_auth_password($con, "userssh", "password")) {
                echo'authentication failed';
            } else {
                //Execute command
                if(!($stream = ssh2_exec($con, "cd ~/scripts; pwd; ./startVM.sh" )) ){
                    echo 'failed executing';
                } else {
                     echo 'sucess';

                }
            }
         }
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. It's awesome :)

Comment: I tried your solution. I got `Call to undefined function App\ssh2_connect()`

Comment: Since, I am on the Mac, I've installed `brew install php56-ssh2` , I still get the same errror. I hope you dont mind filling out what I missed. :)

Comment: try installing SSH2 PECL and check is enabled after restart apache